# Word or phrase that is used to deconstruct another word

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word for phrase for when a word (usually a noun) is broken down into "simpler" words. It might also have derogatory undertones but that is not necessary.

Example 1: Soccer is just "guys kicking a ball"

Example 2: Origami is just "folding paper nicely"

Comment: And an omelet is "just scrambled eggs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [reductionism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reductionism), defined by Merriam Webster as

> A procedure or theory that reduces complex data and phenomena to simple terms.

Also see **reductionism**, defined by [oxford dictionary online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reductionism) as

> The practice of analyzing and describing a complex phenomenon in terms of phenomena that are held to represent a simpler or more fundamental level, especially when this is said to provide a sufficient explanation.