# Is there a word for an explanation that is simple but wrong?

Tags: terminology

Here's an example:

- Child: "Why are trees so tall?"
- Mother: "So we can have a good shadow in summer".

The answer is adequate in the specific context by being simple and [superficially] valid. However, it probably does not resist a more academic or biological analysis.

Is there a name for such type of answer?

I found the word "sophistry" but I'm not sure it applies exactly to this.

Comment: I like H.L. Mencken on this: "For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and wrong."

Comment: What context were you thinking of? A philosophy 101 class? A Facebook argument? Or, to your example, explaining something to a child?

Comment: "Superficial" seemed a good enough word to me.

Comment: @rajah9 I was thinking on an academic context. When I argue a subject and I may fall into a linguistic falsehood.

Comment: Isn't this *begging the question*, where the answer forces the question to be repeated for lack of content?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a word to describe one's thoughts that sound logical and reasonable but, in reality, they are not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532138/what-is-a-word-to-describe-ones-thoughts-that-sound-logical-and-reasonable-but) Or [What is it called when you use wrong but smart arguments?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/514722/what-is-it-called-when-you-use-wrong-but-smart-arguments/514723#514723) Answers include specious & fallacious, as well as casuistry & sophistry.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. I wasn't considering any kind of deceit, as "sophism" would imply. I was considering a less elaborate argument, where a person does not think it through. In this context I think "specious" is more accurate.

Comment: So, already given (I think in both of those threads). 'Simplistic' is given at [looking for 'grossly-oversimplified'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375431/looking-for-grossly-oversimplified/375459#3754590.

Comment: The example shows a parent giving a **fanciful** answer to a child. There’s no intent to deceive. A lexicon of humoristic techniques would be more useful than a standard dictionary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prime candidates are specious and fallacious.

> *specious* = seeming to be right or true, but really wrong or false:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/specious)

> *Fallacious* =
> 1 embodying a fallacy
> a fallacious conclusion
> a fallacious argument
>
> 2 : tending to deceive or mislead : DELUSIVE
> false and fallacious hopes
>
> [[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallacious)

From:

> *fallacy* = an idea that a lot of people think is true but is in fact false:
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fallacy)

The example you quote is more specious than fallacious, because the false notion about shadow is not (to my knowledge) a widespread belief.

Comment: I think "specious" is the right one. I wasn't implying any ill intention (like deception, lying), but just the [intentional or not intentional] limitation in the reasoning. Essentially, not thinking it through.

Comment: I agree that specious lacks the overtones of lying in your example. I am reminded of my belief when small that it would be less windy if there were fewer trees around. And why? Because fewer waving trees would create less wind! Age does occasionally bring a little wisdom.

Comment: Why does a downvoter not explain themselves? They do not help the questioner, they discourage serious answering, and their action can too easily be taken for mere caprice or malice.

Answer (score 1):

In an academic context (which the OP explained in a comment), the particular type of fallacy used is called a *Red Herring*. It is sometimes called the *Chewbacca defense*, after a *South Park* episode.

### Red Herring

> ...the speaker deliberately brings up an irrelevant issue.

(Source: *Thank you for Arguing*, Jay Heinrichs, p. 149)

### Chewbacca Defense

> In a jury trial, a Chewbacca defense is a legal strategy in which a criminal defense lawyer tries to confuse the jury rather than refute the case of the prosecutor. It is an intentional distraction or obfuscation.

> As a Chewbacca defense distracts and misleads, it is an example of a red herring. It is also an example of an irrelevant conclusion, a type of informal fallacy in which one making an argument fails to address the issue in question. Often an opposing counsel can legally object to such arguments by declaring them irrelevant, character evidence, or argumentative.

> The name Chewbacca defense comes from "Chef Aid", an episode of the American animated series South Park. The episode, which premiered on October 7, 1998, satirizes the O. J. Simpson murder trial, particularly attorney Johnnie Cochran's closing argument for the defense. In the episode, Cochran bases his argument on a false premise about the 1983 film Return of the Jedi. He asks the jury why a Wookiee like Chewbacca would want to live on Endor with the much smaller Ewoks when "it does not make sense". He argues that if Chewbacca living on Endor does not make sense—and if even mentioning Chewbacca in the case does not make sense—then the jury must acquit.

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewbacca_defense)

Answer (score 1):

*Specious* is the word you're after. Another word that fits the bill is **simplistic.**

> characterized by extreme and often misleading simplicity

*a simplistic theory of the universe.*

[Etymonline]

Answer (score 0):

The mother's answer was disingenuous.

> **disingenuous**  - lacking in frankness, candor, or sincerity; falsely or hypocritically ingenuous; insincere
> *Her excuse was rather disingenuous*
>
> — https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disingenuous

Answer (score 0):

A [just-so story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-so_story) is an explanation for some phenomenon that makes some amount of sense at first glance, but has no actual research or data to back it up.

The term comes from a book of fanciful stories by Rudyard Kipling titled [*Just So Stories for Little Children*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_So_Stories) that made up fanciful and fictional stories about how different animals ended up with their various characteristics.  For example, in "How the Elephant got his Trunk," a curious elephant child gets too close to a crocodile, which bites its nose and the elephant child stretches it out into a long trunk while trying to escape.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-so_story) you relate to actually has 'In science and philosophy, a just-so story is an **untestable** narrative explanation for ...' (bolding mine). But OP includes 'However, it probably does not resist a more academic or biological analysis', ie is in most cases testable.